# How can I write a conditional without any conditional statements or operators?

Tags: c#, string

My computer teacher wants me to write code to concatenate two strings( in a weird way). The code should be such that if length of both string are equal then output should be (string1 + string2). Otherwise the output should be string which is larger in length. Challenge is that I should not use `if else` statements or `condition?exp1:exp2` whatsoever. This is what I am able to come up with (a and b are names of input string):

```
int aLen = a.Length;
int bLen = b.Length;
//+1 is added to lengths to prevent divide by zero 
int bGreatFlag = ((aLen+1) % (bLen + 1)) / (aLen + 1);  //1 if aLen < bLen; 0 Otherwise
int aGreatFlag = ((bLen+1) % (aLen+1)) / (bLen+1);  //1 if bLen < aLen; 0 Otherwise
string result = (a + b).Substring((bGreatFlag) * aLen,(aLen + bLen)-(bGreatFlag*aLen)-(aGreatFlag*bLen));
```

I believe that there is another way to approach this question which I am missing altogether(an inbuilt function or some LINQ maybe?). Any other approach or any pointers in the right direction to join strings conditionally will be really helpful. Thanks :) . Please be kind if the answer to this is very trivial.

Comment: Have you considered using LINQ to order the strings by their length? N can post an answer showing how, but since this is your teacher asking, perhaps he wants you to learn by experimentation instead of through copy and paste.

Comment: Or using LINQ Max in some way?

Comment: how about using a "switch case" statement?

Comment: Does your teacher know you are using C#? LINQ makes a lot of shortcuts for the developer, but I'm sure it makes use of `if` statements. Make sure he/she doesn't think you're just writing a conditional in a different way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if the goal is to avoid *execution* of an if-statement, that occurs in some framework routine, you're probably out of luck. Even array access will in some way execute the equivalent of an if-statement.

Comment: Can you use `switch`?

Comment: LINQ is allowed, infact he may want me to go there but I am not sure about switch. But even if I use switch it would be another way of implementing if - else (i guess). I was able to get larger of string using LINQ easily,but my code fails in case they both are equal.

Comment: Can you show the code used for this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't think if else should be avoided at framework level, its a programming question after all. But it should not be used in the code that I write.

Comment: @Matthijs Linq for getting larger of two
    string a = "ssadas";
            
            string b = "j";
            string[] e = { a, b };
            var sorted = from s in e
                         orderby s.Length descending
                         select s;
            string result = sorted.ElementAt(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're allowed to use LINQ, here's a possible solution:

But your strings into a collection, group it by the length of its string, order the result by the length of the strings, then take the group with the longest strings. Since now you have a collection of either both strings (if they are of equal length) or the longer one, create a string of this collection by using `String.Join`.

**Spoiler** (don't miss the fun of implementing this yourself):

> var result = String.Join("", new[]{a, b}.GroupBy(x => x.Length).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).First().ToArray());

Comment: I was able to do it using your pointers. But now I see your code and i think my code is somewhat messy than yours. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Math.Sign to determine which length is greater. Hope this helps...

```
string a, b, result;
switch (Math.Sign(a.Length - b.Length))
{
    case 1: result = a; break;
    case -1: result = b; break;
    default: result = a + b; break;
}
```

Comment: You could also use `(a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length))` (but `CompareTo` returning `1`/`-1` is just an implementation detail you should not rely on, so `Math.Sign` is probably better).

Answer (score 0):

try using while like this

```
        string r = "bla", rr = "blabla";
        while (rr.Length > r.Length)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("it works");
            break;
        }
```

where the r and rr is a example of the two strings and when it enters the break serves to make it run only once so it would work like a if...

Answer (score 0):

Since I liked your way of doing it I improved it a bit for you:

```
            string a = "strin";
        string b = "string";
        string combined = (a + b);

        int aLength = a.Length; 
        int bLength = b.Length; 
        int aCheck = (aLength % bLength) / aLength;  
        int bCheck = (bLength % aLength) / bLength; 

        // If aCheck and bCheck are both 0 (same length) it isn't going to add any characters from the substring as
        // aLength * 0 = 0. If either aCheck or bCheck is 1 then it will add the length from aLength again to the string.
        string result = combined += combined.Substring(0, (aLength * (aCheck + bCheck)));
        result += combined.Substring(0, (bLength * bCheck)); ;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Your code results in `result` being `strinstringstrin` instead of `string`.

Comment: This would add the shorter string to (string1 + string2). What I want is little bit different. Thanks for the effort :)

Comment: didn't see your last line when I commented. This works :) . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per other's comments, your teacher doesn't exclude all the branches possible, e.g. you could use a `while` and break after one loop. `switch` would be my favourite, with the use of `CompareTo()` to reduce the range of output to `-1, 0 and 1`:

```
     switch ((s1.Length - s2.Length).CompareTo(0))
     {
        case -1: // s1 less than s2
           return s2;
        case 1: // s1 greater than s2
           return s1;
        case 0: // equal length
           return s1 + s2;
     }
```

Comment: Just note that while this works, you shouldn't rely on `CompareTo` returning `-1` and `1` (at least not in real world code), since it's just an implementation detail. `CompareTo` just promise to return a number `> 0`, `0` or `< 0`.

Comment: Well, yes, I guess this is code golf, not real world code.